# Hide columns using VBA in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

Based on the value stored in a specific cell such as `A1` of a worksheet I would like to hide a number of columns in the worksheet starting with column B.

Examples of what I am trying to do:

- If the value of cell A1 = 10, then hide column B plus 10 columns after B
- If the value of cell A2 = 11, then hide column B plus 11 columns after B

The difficulty is actually the way Excel (or least my Excel files) uses the alphabet (A, B, ...) for the name of the columns. I have done this on rows before using code like `rows("2:" & range("A1").value)` and set `.hide = true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference columns by their index number as such: [`Columns(indexnumber)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa214202%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and you can use [`Resize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to set the number of columns you want to select like so:

```
Sub HideColumns()
    Dim numColumnsToHide

    numColumnsToHide = Cells(1, 1).Value

    Columns(2).Resize(, numColumnsToHide).Select

    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Obviously, this code doesn't have any validation of value in `A1` so if someone runs `HideColumns()` without an integer in `A1`, bad things are going to happen. This also doesn't unhide any hidden columns.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works well. Just an extension to the existed question.  What if I want to hide columns from other sheet(s) for example sheeet1?  I try Sheets("Sheet1"). Columns(2).Resize(, numColumnsToHide).Select but this reference method is invalid

Comment: You need to make Sheet2 the active worksheet. You can do this by adding `Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate` after you set the value of numCOlumnsToHide but before before the `Columns(2).Resize...` line

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add a comment to Glenn's answer above but don't have enough reputation. What I was going to add was that you don't need to activate a sheet or select the columns, you can simply go ahead and hide the columns:

```
Worksheets("TheSheet").Columns(2).Resize(, numColumnsToHide).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Please to not complicate just do it

Sub ocultaColunas()

Range("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End Sub